# CSS left:25% not working the same across browsers?

Tags: css

I have a slider image on a [homepage](http://www.stonevillachester.co.uk)

For some reason, in Firefox and Safari the image is displaying to the right. In Chrome, it is displaying in the centre as it should.

I believe this is down to the positioning however the changes I have tried done appear to help much.

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: It's not displaying in the centre in chrome for me (OSX, v22)

Comment: Your `div#slider-container` has `margin-left:25%`, is this expected? It's not displaying center in my poor 1024 width screen in Chrome either.

Comment: Apologies, im attemping fixes on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your CSS to:

```
#slider-container{ 

width:960px;
position: relative;
overflow:hidden;
height:300px;
z-index:100;
border-bottom:1px solid #2b292d; padding-bottom:20px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0px auto;
}


#content-wrapper{ position:relative; z-index:200; bottom:-50px;}
```

Comment: This worked great thank you. I think I was misplacing the margin and text-align commands. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

..............

Hi now define you **slide id** `left 50%` and give to `margin-left: - half` of `slider width`

**as like this.**

```
#slider-container{
left:50%;
margin-left:-480px;  // total width of 980px half
}
```

Result is https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpR3v.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Set the margin property of the element to `0 auto`, and then set the parent element's `text-align` property to `center`